# What is the variance of the forecast error for a horizon $\ h$?

Tags: time-series, variance, forecasting, prediction, moving-average

Consider the following time series model

$\ Z_t = \mu + a_t$

where $\mu$ is the level and $\ a_t$ is the random component.

For this model, the level is a moving average process of order 6, $\ MA(6)$; hence the forecasting equation for$\ h$ steps ahead can be written as:

$\hat{Z}_t(h) = \hat{l}  $, where $\hat{l}$ is the estimator of $\mu$.

I read that the variance of the forecasting equation is $\ var[\hat{Z}_t(h)] = \sigma_a^2/n^2$ where $\ n $ is the order of my $\ MA$ process. That means it doesn't matter if my forecasting horizon is 1 or a 1000, the variance will always be the same for every forecasted value.

It's also clear taht the higher the value of $\ n$, the lower is the variance of forecasted value.

> Question: what is then the variance of the forecasting error for h steps ahead in terms of $\ n$?

If the forecast error calculated at origin $\ T$ for a horizon $\ h$ is defined as: $\ e_T(h) = (Z_{T+1} - \hat{Z}_T(h)) $, the variance of the error is $\sigma_{e_T}^2 = var(Z_{T+1}) - var(\hat{Z}_T(h))) $.

> How do I get the equation for $\sigma_{e_T}^2 $in terms of $\ n$?

Comment: No, the variance doesn't change with time

Comment: You mention variance of the forecast error, variance of the forecasting equation and variance of the forecasted value. Could you check once again if what you have written is what you actually mean?

Comment: Hey, @RichardHardy, is there a difference between the variance of the forecast error and the forecasted value? I am probably wrong then, because I thought the forecast error can only be understood as difference between the forecasted value and the actual value. Hence, the variance for the forecast error is the difference between the var. of the model equation and the var. of the forecast equation for any specific horizon. Is this wrong? Also, made an edit to try to clarify my statements. Thanks for your input.